# Using MySql Update and PHP for smilies

Tags: php, mysql, image, function, replace

I am fairly new to PHP and very new to MySql.  I found this line of code online and am using it in a function that fetches all of the messages in a conversation (on my messaging system using php/mysql):

```
        $sql = "UPDATE `conversations_messages` SET message_text = REPLACE(message_text, '\r\n', '<br />')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Obviously, this is so that line breaks appear as `<br />`

My question is this: (how) could I incorporate this code to set :) into an image of a smiley face?

Please help me.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This code is awful. You should not execute it.

The database should always contain the data the user entered. No HTML code! If one deviates from this rule, one should know exactly why and when.

You should transform characters into smileys or transform `\n` into `<br>` while outputting the text instead. For example like this:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
$text = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $text);
$text = str_replace(":)", '<img src="smiley.png" />', $text);
echo $text;
```

while `$text` is filled previously by a select statement.

Comment: +1, Took my answer before i had chance to write it :) P.S use the `nl2br` instead of `<br />`.

Comment: @GhostGambler I have a $messages array.  Would this work for that?

Comment: Sure, you just have to use an array value instead of `$text`.

Comment: For some reason,      $messages['message_text'] = htmlspecialchars($messages['message_text']);
$messages['message_text'] = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $messages['message_text']);       gives me an error

Comment: Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Comment: Also, there are no line breaks

Comment: I think I may have sorted it, sorry

Comment: no, I haven't fixed it; strtostring removes the error, however the date then becomes invalid

Comment: As long as we do not see what you are working on, we cannot help.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `UTF-8` character directly

You may use (assuming `UTF-8`) directly ["smiley face character"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263a/index.htm), its hex sequence is `0xE2 0x98 0xBA (e298ba)`:

```sql
mysql> SELECT CHAR(0xe298ba USING UTF8);
+---------------------------+
| CHAR(0xe298ba USING UTF8) |
+---------------------------+
| ☺                         |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I do **NOT** recommend doing this (but you it's possible), if you really want to store modified data in the database rather use HTML entry `&#x263a` (which won't put any special characters into database).

```sql
UPDATE `conversations_messages` 
    SET message_text = REPLACE(message_text, ':)', '&#x263a;')
```

Of course this assumes you don't do any html filtering (like [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)) after loading data from database.

But I wouldn't store modified data in the database (at least not without storing original version), imagine scenario when you would want to add new smiley face after "processing" every message you already have (or worse remove it)...

If you (for some reason) **really** have to replace it as a par of "model" rather use:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(`message_text`, ':)', '&#x263a;') AS message_text
```

Or rather build [stored function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines-syntax.html) which will do multiple steps (replace newlines, smiley faces and so on).

```sql
SELECT MyProcessingFunction(`message_text`) AS message_text
```

Much more suitable way of doing this will be "decorating text" when it's printed out

```php
function process_text($text)
{
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
    $text = str_replace( '\n', '<br />', $text);
    $text = str_replace( ':)', '&@x263a;', $text);
    return $text;
}

$message_text = do_some_magic();
echo process_text($message_text);
```

This way you still have original available and can change formatting on the fly without corrupting old data.

#### Using `<img />` tag

Much more common way (at least in my experience) is using images (small images):

```php
function process_text($text)
{
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
    $text = str_replace( '\n', '<br />', $text);
    $text = str_replace( ':)', '<img class="smiley" src="..." alt=":)" />', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

This will give you much more freedom (use your own smileys, style them a bit) when doing things.

#### Another tips

You can use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) instead of replacing newlines manually (but last time I've worked with it, it wasn't XHTML compatible... which it is since `4.0.5`).

Also [sanitize user inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) (database input - prepared statements and parameters; output - `htmlspecialchars()` or equivalent) to prevent users from [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) or just screwing up your page.

Comment: I have done the 'Using <img /> tag' method you provided, but I get the error: Warning: str_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given

Comment: Ah, wrote code from the tom of my head added `, $text` to examples (please study examples before using them... this way you may execute malicious code + you probably won't learn how the things work).

Comment: I decided to use html instead